# How can I define an enum in Rust with references that can be either mutable or immutable

Tags: rust, enums

I have an `Enum MyEnum` which contains two arms, each holds a reference to a different type: `i32` and `f64`.

I'm trying to define a trait with two functions:

`get`: Should return a `MyEnum` instance with an immutable reference to the value.

`get_mut`: Should return a `MyEnum` instance with a mutable reference to the value.

I'm failing to find the right syntax for this. The code below doesn't compile

```
enum MyEnum<'a> {
    Integer(&'a i32),
    Real(&'a f64),
}

struct MyIntegerStruct {
    x:i32,
}

trait MyTrait {
    fn get(&self) -> MyEnum;
    
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> MyEnum;
}

impl MyTrait for MyIntegerStruct {
    fn get(&self) -> MyEnum {
        MyEnum::Integer(&self.x)
    }
    
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> MyEnum {
        MyEnum::Integer(&mut self.x)
    }
    
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyIntegerStruct {
        x:42,
    };
    let myenum = s.get_mut();
    match myenum {
        MyEnum::Integer(&mut val) => *val = 17,
        _ => panic!()
    };
}
```

Error message:

```
   error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> src/main.rs:33:25
       |
    32 |     match myenum {
       |           ------ this expression has type `MyEnum<'_>`
    33 |         MyEnum::Integer(&mut val) => *val = 17,
       |                         ^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
       |
       = note:      expected reference `&i32`
               found mutable reference `&mut _`
    note: to declare a mutable binding use: `mut val`
      --> src/main.rs:33:25
       |
    33 |         MyEnum::Integer(&mut val) => *val = 17,
       |                         ^^^^^^^^
    help: consider removing `&mut` from the pattern
       |
    33 |         MyEnum::Integer(val) => *val = 17,
       |                         ~~~
```

Comment: `&T` and `&mut T` are different types, your enum can only hold the former. There is no being generic over mutability currently in Rust.

Comment: But see https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2022/07/27/keyword-generics.html for future directions Rust might go to solve this problem